# TFS Rest API not working for logs

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild

Any idea why this method does not work:

```
GET https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/logs?api-version=2.0
```

I am able to get build definition, etc. but when I try to get log based on this build ID, I'm getting this error:

> {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"This API is only
>   applicable to logs stored in the file
>   container.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.InvalidLogLocationException,
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi, Version=14.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","typeKey":"InvalidLogLocationException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a supported API, but the following works for me.

VSTS: https://{instance}.visualstudio.com/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildid}/logs?$format=zip

TFS: http://{instance}/Collection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/81590/logs?$format=zip

Comment: It works, thank you! When I add `$format=zip&api-version=2.0`

Comment: Any idea how to get it in JSON format without getting zip file and going trough the files?

Comment: I am able to use the same uri that you posted to get the log summary: https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/logs and then use https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/logs/{LogId} to get each of the individual logs.

Comment: Can you please try with VSTS version?

Comment: In VSTS it's working exactly as described https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#logs I responded with the format=zip because I thought you were trying to get all of the logs in one request. As far as I know, you can't do that and receive a json response