# TFS build logging

Tags: azure, tfs

is there any option of displaying the build logs inside TFS, instead of downloading them as a zip file?

(the Logs link isn't working).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you either view them through the logs link or download them. The only other option is to pull them down [using the API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743037/tfs-rest-api-not-working-for-logs). I suggest you troubleshoot and fix the logs link.