# How do I programmatically add attachments to test results during a build in VSTS?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm looking for a way to add my own attachments to test results so that I can see them after a build has completed here...

[image]

I would like to add these programmatically, during a build and after a test has failed. The attachments will be screenshots.

Is this possible?

I had a quick look at the `API` reference but this looked to be concerned with adding attachments to existing test 'runs', or on the build, the side was for creating build definitions and triggering them. I may have missed it but I couldn't find how to add attachments from code during or immediately after a test task had completed.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you write the test with Specflow & Selenium?

Answer (score 3):

[You could get test run of the build first and then retrieve the test result from the test run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39373499/how-to-get-unit-test-results-using-tfs-rest-api):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ur = "https://xxxxxxx/";
        TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(ur));
        //Get build information
        BuildHttpClient bhc = ttpc.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>();
        string projectname = "Project";
        int buildId = x;
        Build bui = bhc.GetBuildAsync(projectname,buildId).Result;
        //Get test run for the build
        TestManagementHttpClient ithc = ttpc.GetClient<TestManagementHttpClient>();

        Console.WriteLine(bui.BuildNumber);

        QueryModel qm = new QueryModel("Select * From TestRun Where BuildNumber Contains '" + bui.BuildNumber + "'");

        List<TestRun> testruns = ithc.GetTestRunsByQueryAsync(qm,projectname).Result;
        foreach (TestRun testrun in testruns)
        {

            List<TestCaseResult> testresults = ithc.GetTestResultsAsync(projectname, testrun.Id).Result;
            foreach (TestCaseResult tcr in testresults)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(tcr.Id);
                    Console.WriteLine(tcr.Outcome);
                }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Once you get failed test result id, you could use [Rest API to attach a file to test result](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/test/attachments#attach-a-file-to-a-test-result):

```
POST https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/test/runs/{run}/results/{result}/attachments?api-version={version}
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "stream": { string },
  "fileName": { string },
  "comment": { string },
  "attachmentType": { string }
}
```